# How to update Intellij Idea Dynamic Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, gradle-plugin

There are [Dynamic Plugins](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/dynamic_plugins.html) in 2020.1+ Jetbrains IDEs.

How can we now hotswap plugin with recent one in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `idea.auto.reload.plugins` system property https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/ide_development_instance.html#enabling-auto-reload

Comment: Thanks! In my case I set `idea.auto.reload.plugins=true` in `gradle.properties`